# Not able to retrieve values from chrome.storage.sync.get when passing XML data from background page

Tags: javascript

I am receiving data through an XML request from sheets in background page. I am trying to pass this data to content js file.

When I am try to receive the data in `content.js` using `chrome.storage.sync.get` its throwing undefined.

Please help me in fixing this.

In `background.js`

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'xmldata':xmldata}) 
//added in background.js
//(when I add a callback function and get the console.log(xmldata) its displaying the values)
```

In `content.js`

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('xmldata',function(result){console.log(xmldata})
//trying this in contentjs it displays undefined
```

Comment: Use this instead `console.log('xmldata', result);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead `console.log('xmldata', result);`

Because you have no referrer from variable `result` from `function(result)`

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['xmldata'], function(result) {
   console.log('Value currently is ' + result.xmldata);
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply..I missed to update a line of code in my content.js which i mentioned previously,iactually used below code in contentjs chrome.storage.sync.get('xmldata',function(result){console.log(result.xmldata})..Could you please confirm me if the above solution will still work?

Comment: I have updated and this for refer https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#using-sync

Comment: Its not working..I have tried using the above code as per your code..Its not working.